# Ember Guide replacing LocalDSAdapter with REST Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I completed the ember getting started todo guide.

i then built a JSON Webapi using the correct naming conventions.

ember successfully calls the api and retrives the information i then get the following error messages, and i am unsure on how i am going to debug this

```
Assertion failed: No model was found for '0' ember.js:394
(anonymous function) ember.js:394
Ember.assert ember.js:53
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor ember-data-latest.js:2177
DS.RESTSerializer.DS.JSONSerializer.extend.extractArray ember-data-latest.js:6403
superWrapper ember.js:1218
(anonymous function) ember-data-latest.js:89
DS.JSONSerializer.Ember.Object.extend.extract ember-data-latest.js:196
(anonymous function) ember-data-latest.js:2649
invokeCallback ember.js:8055
(anonymous function) ember.js:8105
EventTarget.trigger ember.js:7878
(anonymous function) ember.js:8172
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:5459
Backburner.end ember.js:5545
Backburner.run ember.js:5584
Ember.run ember.js:5915
hash.success ember-data-latest.js:7115
l jquery.js:9597
c.fireWith jquery.js:9597
k jquery.js:9597
(anonymous function) jquery.js:9597




Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember.js:394
(anonymous function) ember.js:394
Ember.Router.reopenClass._defaultErrorHandler ember.js:30563
triggerEvent ember.js:30520
trigger ember.js:29641
handleError ember.js:29903
invokeCallback ember.js:8055
(anonymous function) ember.js:8109
EventTarget.trigger ember.js:7878
(anonymous function) ember.js:8180
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:5459
Backburner.end ember.js:5545
Backburner.run ember.js:5584
Ember.run ember.js:5915
hash.success ember-data-latest.js:7115
l jquery.js:9597
c.fireWith jquery.js:9597
k jquery.js:9597
(anonymous function) jquery.js:9597


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined ember-data-latest.js:2179
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor ember-data-latest.js:2179
DS.RESTSerializer.DS.JSONSerializer.extend.extractArray ember-data-latest.js:6403
superWrapper ember.js:1218
(anonymous function) ember-data-latest.js:89
DS.JSONSerializer.Ember.Object.extend.extract ember-data-latest.js:196
(anonymous function) ember-data-latest.js:2649
invokeCallback ember.js:8055
(anonymous function) ember.js:8105
EventTarget.trigger ember.js:7878
(anonymous function) ember.js:8172
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:5459
Backburner.end ember.js:5545
Backburner.run ember.js:5584
Ember.run ember.js:5915
hash.success ember-data-latest.js:7115
l jquery.js:9597
c.fireWith jquery.js:9597
k jquery.js:9597
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the payload returned from the server, is missing the root key of the json array, for example:

```
this.store.find('user')
```

The expected response from server is:

```
{
  users: [ ... ]
}
```

Probally you are using:

```
[...]
```

If you see this fiddle the same error is throwed, because the missing `people` http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8GfG4/